# VBA Array/Dictionary IF formula and SUMIF

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to switch to VBA arrays with one of my Excel Workbook as it has multiple sheets which are referencing a sheet with 50K + rows and columns from A to AK. There's a bunch of IFs,SUMIFs and VLookUps.  It takes about 10 minutes for excel to fully calculate all the formulas and complete the data I need, then some other minutes to save what I need with values only and no formulas.

I'm new to VBA and only managed to convert the vlookups and that cut the processing time of said formulas to almost instant. Now I'm trying to convert the IF/SUMifs formulas...but for some reason I just can't wrap my mind about how to approach this/find a solution online.

Using the below code I'm adding the two columns I need for my IF formula, about this I'm about 90% sure as I'm using the same one(reading different columns) for the vlookup code which works perfectly. So it should work here as well for mapping the dictionary and array.

```
'Array variable
Dim arr() As Variant
'Dictionary object
Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


'Read data into array
With Sheets("test")
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'Range(C2:Cx where x is last row in column C)
    arr = .Cells(2, 3).Resize(x - 1).Value
End With


'Map arr into dictionary
For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    'dic(match column) = return column
    dic(arr(x, 1)) = arr(x, 3)
Next x
'Clear array contents
Erase arr


With Sheets("test")
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    'Read values from column D into array
    'Range(D2:Dx, where x is last row in column D)
    arr = .Cells(2, 4).Resize(x - 1).Value
```

Now I'm trying to convert the following formula `=IF(ROW(A2)=1,"Vendor",IF(D2="",C2," **"&C2))` into VBA. I guess the ideal way would be through a loop and to store the values in arr and then output to my desired column, but I can't think of an approach for this.  I've tried a For combined with IF but with no success. This is what I've tried with no success:

```
For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
If dic(arr(x, 1)) <> "" Then
arr(x, 1) = "**" & arr(x,1)
```

Also I have a bunch of SUMIFs which are basically the same formula with different
criteria : `=SUMIFS(L:L,AE:AE,AE2,E:E,E2,AF:AF,AF2)`. But for this one except for mapping the whole sheet into an array/dictionary I have no idea what to do.

I'm new to all VBA and at this point I'm entirely stuck. Any help would be useful:).

Comment: So you are trying to do all the calculations in the array? What exactly is the problem with your second bit of code?

Comment: Yea I'm trying to do everything in the array. Well it doesn't return what the IF formula returns. What it should do is: If D2 has no value it will output in my desired column (let's say X) the value in C2. if there's a value in D2 it should show the value in C2 with ** in front. I.e D2="23", C2="Key", X2="**Key".

Comment: But what corresponds to A, C and D in your array? Btw `ROW(A2)=1` doesn't make much sense as will never be true.

Comment: I've got rid of A in array. Column C  should be the dictionary from my code and column D should be arr.

Comment: not really? i populate the array move the data to dic then clear the array and populate with column D. :-?

Comment: Yes ok scratch that. But initially `arr` is an x by 1 array `arr = .Cells(2, 3).Resize(x - 1).Value` but then you refer to `arr(x, 3)` which must error.

Comment: It doesn't error as there's a for x =; it runs through the column and gets all the values in the said column. Like I said...populating the array/dictionary works fine. I'm stuck at converting the IF and SUMIF into array calculation

Comment: It errors not because the `x` is out of row-range, but because `3` is out of column-range... Please see my adjustment in the code of my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Dictionary here. Better use an 2-D Array and another Array for output.
Then just loop and assign the values like the following:

```
'Read data into array
With Sheets("test")
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'Range(C2:Cx where x is last row in column C)
    arr = .Cells(2, 3).Resize(x - 1, 2).Value   ' CHANGE: All needed columns

    ReDim OutArr(1 To UBound(arr))
    For x = 1 To UBound(arr)
        OutArr(x) = IIf(arr(x, 2) = "", " **", "") & arr(x, 1)
    Next x
    .Cells(2, 5).Resize(UBound(OutArr)).Value = OutArr  ' Change column if needed

End With
```